# How to see Crash Overview on Analytics console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am able to see crash overview in Analytics console on MFP development server but coming to MFP enterprise server I couldn't see that.

should I enable it some where?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crash overview is part of a feature in release, meaning that we put that feature into an ifix. If you want to see crash data on your analytics production server then you will need to upgrade the analytics.ear/analytics war files in your production server.

It was a feature in 7.1 in December 2015, so any 2016 build you will have crash charts.